# Cloud Storage for Firebase access error "admin.storage(...).ref is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am working with Cloud Storage for Firebase and can't figure out how to to access storage files

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start official guide and https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference this code should be returning root reference

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({...})
let storageRef = admin.storage().ref()
```

But it throws an error saying

> TypeError: admin.storage(...).ref is not a function

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1",
    "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

node -v => 
**v7.7.4**

My end goal it to download files or upload a pdf file to storage.

Comment: are you on functions? if so, use `bucket = admin.storage().bucket()`, functions admin does not use the web apis

Comment: Thank you for replying, yes, I can access bucket this way and can access file using `bucket.file('images/snow.jpg')` but i want to return/download file in response of cloud function. Can you guide?

Comment: I have tried `bucket.file('images/snow.jpg').getDownloadURL()` but it says 
`bucket.file(...).getDownloadURL is not a function`

Comment: because its not. See available functions: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/File

Comment: Hey .. I keep getting .. Error: Cannot sign data without `client_email`. where can I configure client_email ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using Cloud Functions and the Firebase Admin SDK to try and access your bucket. The Getting Started guide you cited is talking about client sided Web Apps with the Web API for Firebase not the Admin one. The functionality there is different, because it uses a different SDK (even if their names are the same).

The `Storage` Object you are trying to access doesn't have the `ref()` functions, only `app` and `bucket()`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.storage

Try using the Google Cloud APIs directly:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-nodejs

-

EDIT:
This edit is only to stop scaring people with a post from two years ago. The answer above still applies as of May 2020.

Comment: It's a perfect explanation for a common confusion. I think that Firebase's documentation could be much better. Your simple answer has made me save a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: is that still true as of March 2020? If no, any plans to include storage api to the admin sdk?

Comment: Still true as of APR 2020. Firebase's documentation could've highlighted this better.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage      link is not found , could you plz update a alternative link ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage

Comment: Updated, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 3):

In the below example, I am extracting image references from an existing Firestore collection called "images".  I am cross referencing the "images" collection with the "posts" collection such that I only get images that relate to a certain post.  This is not required.

[Docs for getSignedUrl()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.4.x/File#getSignedUrl)

```
const storageBucket = admin.storage().bucket( 'gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE}.appspot.com' )
const getRemoteImages = async() => {
    const imagePromises = posts.map( (item, index) => admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('images')
        .where('postId', '==', item.id)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            // querySnapshot is an array but I only want the first instance in this case
            const docRef = querySnapshot.docs[0] 
            // the property "url" was what I called the property that holds the name of the file in the "posts" database
            const fileName = docRef.data().url 
            return storageBucket.file( fileName ).getSignedUrl({
                action: "read",
                expires: '03-17-2025' // this is an arbitrary date
            })
        })
        // chained promise because "getSignedUrl()" returns a promise
        .then((data) => data[0]) 
        .catch(err => console.log('Error getting document', err))
    )
    // returns an array of remote image paths
    const imagePaths = await Promise.all(imagePromises)
    return imagePaths
}
```

Here is the important part consolidated:

```
const storageBucket = admin.storage().bucket( 'gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE}.appspot.com' )
const fileName = "file-name-in-storage" // ie: "your-image.jpg" or "images/your-image.jpg" or "your-pdf.pdf" etc.
const remoteImagePath = storageBucket.file( fileName ).getSignedUrl({
    action: "read",
    expires: '03-17-2025' // this is an arbitrary date
})
.then( data => data[0] )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want temporary links to all images in a folder in a Cloud Storage Bucket, the following code snippet will achieve it. In this example, I query for all images under the folder `images/userId`.

```js
exports.getImagesInFolder = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket('gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE}');
    const query = {
        directory: `images/${req.body.userId}` // query for images under images/userId
    };
    
    const [files] = await storageRef.getFiles(query)
    const urls = await Promise.all(files.map(file => file.getSignedUrl({
        action: "read",
        expires: '04-05-2042' // this is an arbitrary date
    })))

    return res.send({ urls })
})
```

API Documentation:

- [getFiles](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles)
- [getSignedUrl](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getSignedUrl)

**PS**: Please keep in mind that this might allow *anyone* to pass a `userId` and query for all images for this specific user.